# unable to create SED command to make changes in lines other than starting with specific words

Tags: sed

I am working on a html project and have to manipulate a huge number of files, so i am using sed, head & tail for the work but now i got stuck at this point.

Strings to delete`<i><font color="#000000"> and <font color="#000000"><i>`

but not in lines that starts with `<b><font color="#000000"><p align="JUSTIFY"> and <p align="JUSTIFY"> and </font></b><p align="JUSTIFY">`

By the way i have written one but can't figure out whats the problem with it

```
sed -rei '/^<b><font color="#000000"><p align="JUSTIFY">RELATIONS.|<p align="JUSTIFY">|</font></b><p align="JUSTIFY">/! s/<font color="#0000ff"><i>|<i><font color="#0000ff">//g'
```

Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Regards

Edit: After looking at the htmls again i got to know that we actually want to edit from 8th line till end except the last line of all files

Example

```
line 1 <i>some text<i>
line 2 <i>some text<i>
line 3 <i>some text<i>
line 4 <i>some text<i>
line 5 <i>some text<i>
line 6 <i>some text<i>
line 7 <i>some text<i>
line 8 <i>some text<i>
line 9 <i>some text<i>
line 10 <i>some text<i>
S       <i>some text<i>
o       <i>some text<i>
-       <i>some text<i>
o       <i>some text<i>
n       <i>some text<i>   
line N <i>some text<i>
```

To

```
line 1 <i>some text<i>
line 2 <i>some text<i>
line 3 <i>some text<i>
line 4 <i>some text<i>
line 5 <i>some text<i>
line 6 <i>some text<i>
line 7 <i>some text<i>
line 8 some text
line 9 some text
line 10 some text
S       some text
o       some text
-       some text
o       some text
n       some text   
line N <i>some text<i>
```

Comment: `sed -rei` gives me ``-e expression #1, char 1: expected \ after `a', `c' or `i'``

Comment: Though I know Sed a little bit but very weak in comman and extended expressions. I have also tried the back slash but with out any sucess. Sorry but i can't understand you properly.

Comment: Silly but what that means how can i do the job, the correct method?

Comment: My guess is that the </b> (for example) uses the '/' character, which disrupts your pattern, which is specified by using '/' at the beginning. Choose another delimiter, like sed -rei '#^<b>....'

Comment: @cmonkey nothing changed, Thanks for your input :)

Comment: @user2294943, cmonkey has the right answer. You should escape all the slashes in your pattern: `/^<b>....<\/b>/!`

Answer (score 0):

Just use awk:

```
awk '!/^(<b><font color="#000000"><p align="JUSTIFY">|<p align="JUSTIFY">|<\/font><\/b><p align="JUSTIFY">)/{ gsub(/<i><font color="#000000">|<font color="#000000"><i>/,"") } 1' file
```

Now I'm getting a better feel for your requirements, you can condense the initial condition a bit to:

```
awk '!/^(<b><font color="#000000">|<\/font><\/b>)?<p align="JUSTIFY">)/{ gsub(/<i><font color="#000000">|<font color="#000000"><i>/,"") } 1' file
```

Given your new requirement which is apparently to simply remove all `<i>`s from line 8 to the line before the last line, how about this:

```
$ cat file
line 1 <i>some text<i>
line 2 <i>some text<i>
line 3 <i>some text<i>
line 4 <i>some text<i>
line 5 <i>some text<i>
line 6 <i>some text<i>
line 7 <i>some text<i>
line 8 <i>some text<i>
line 9 <i>some text<i>
line 10 <i>some text<i>
S       <i>some text<i>
o       <i>some text<i>
-       <i>some text<i>
o       <i>some text<i>
n       <i>some text<i>
line N <i>some text<i>

$ awk -v numLines=$(wc -l<file) 'NR>7 && NR<numLines{gsub(/<i>/,"")}1' file
line 1 <i>some text<i>
line 2 <i>some text<i>
line 3 <i>some text<i>
line 4 <i>some text<i>
line 5 <i>some text<i>
line 6 <i>some text<i>
line 7 <i>some text<i>
line 8 some text
line 9 some text
line 10 some text
S       some text
o       some text
-       some text
o       some text
n       some text
line N <i>some text<i>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i think there must be some problem, the command just deleted all <i> and <font color="000000"> from all lines all files.

Comment: That's what you asked for. You said `Strings to delete <i><font color="#000000"> and <font color="#000000"`. What is the issue? It did not delete all <i>s, just the ones matching the pattern you specified. Maybe you should updated your question to show some representative input and the expected output from that input.

Comment: Oh hang on, I think I see the issue - When you said not in lines that starts with `<b><font color="#000000"><p align="JUSTIFY"> and <p align="JUSTIFY"> and </font></b><p align="JUSTIFY">` I took that as a single string - you probably meant to write 3 separate strings separated by "or" instead of "and". I'll update my answer.

Comment: I am really sorry its either <i><font color="#000000" or <font color="#000000"><i>. Gonna edit the question. But still after changing the command a bit to fit my need it does not seem to do the thing. And can i pipe it to create a new file after editing?

Comment: I've updated my answer but you REALLY should provide some sample/input output in your question. Of course you can pipe it to whatever you want, it's just a UNIX command like any other. Having said that, you may not need to as awk is pretty uesful in itself!

Comment: Every thing is fine but AWK is not ignoring lines starting with any of above mentioned. By the way i have to go to home now its too late gonna check again after dinner thanks for your time and help

Comment: Again - post some sample input and expected output. Without that, i can't even test my solution.

Comment: Sorry for delay [link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5626404/) We want to remove <i> from 8th line to end except the last line

Comment: Why not post sample input in your question instead of providing a link to some other site? I can't even access that site due to the firewall at work. Also - POST THE EXPECTED OUTPUT! Don't just tell us about it as that's clearly ambiguous.

Comment: Sorry for that but now after examining all files i think line range would be much more simple, as we only want to change from 8th line to end except the last line. What do u think?

Comment: I've no idea as I haven't seen your sample input and expected output yet.

Comment: Given your new requirements and sample input/output I've updated my answer, see above.

Answer (score 0):

Use a different delimiter:

```
sed -rei 'X^(<b><font color="#000000"><p align="JUSTIFY">)|(<p align="JUSTIFY">)|(</font></b><p align="JUSTIFY">)X! sX(<font color="#0000ff"><i>)|(<i><font color="#0000ff">)XXg'
```

Note how I used `X` as the delimiter, because your regex contains forward slashes, and if you used the typical delimiter of a slash you would have to escape them, which is a hassle that I avoided.

Also your regex had the text RELATIONS buried in it, which I removed .

Comment: Dont know why but its giving an empty file ? I want to specify line range from 8th line to end except the last line instead of line starting from.